# Regex Grouping returns no values

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get some named groups(X, Y, Z, W, P, R) from a string and I'm having problems getting the  output.

This is the part of the string that has the info I am trying to extract:

```
[1,1] = Group: 1   Config:
X:  -196.999   Y:   1009.999   Z:  210.342
W:  90   P:   0   R:  90
```

I tried to get the values using the following

```
@"(?<X>(?<=X:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?))
  (?<Y>(?<=Y:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?))
  (?<Z>(?<=Z:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?))
  (?<W>(?<=W:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?))
  (?<P>(?<=P:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?))
  (?<R>(?<=R:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?))"
```

but I didn't get any values.

Only when I use `@"(?<X>(?<=X:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*Y:))"` do I get the correct value for the X Group.

However this

```
@"(?<X>(?<=X:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*Y:))
  (?<Y>(?<=Y:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*Z:))"
```

Also doesn't give me any values.

Eventually matching `Config:\s*` will also come into play and when I try this

```
@"(?<=Config:\s*)(?<X>(?<=X:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*Y:))"
```

I don't get a value, but this does

```
@"(?<=:\s*)(?<X>(?<=X:\s*)([+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*Y:))"
```

So, A) I don't understand why I need the lookahead `(?=\s*Y:)` to get the value

B) Why does it fail if I add another group?

C) Why am I not matching Config?

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a different approach where you just try to find each letter label and its associated float value:

```
string input = "[1,1] = Group: 1   Config:\nX:  -196.999   Y:   1009.999  \nZ:  210.342\nW:  90   P:   0   R:  90";
var re = new Regex(@"\b([A-Z]+):\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b");
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(input);
for (int mnum = 0; mnum < matches.Count; mnum++)
{
    Match match = matches[mnum];
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", match.Groups[1], match.Groups[2]);
}
```

This prints:

```
X: -196.999
Y: 1009.999
Z: 210.342
W: 90
P: 0
R: 90
```

This approach completely avoids the problem of using named capture groups, and instead just tries to match and capture a letters label, followed by a floating point number.

Comment: OK, so I was just way overthinking this, typical. Also thanks for solving my next problem of how to capture when the file uses X, Y, Z, A, E, R variables.